# copy result of unique() string vector in a dataframe R

Tags: r, vector, copy, dataframe

I am puzzled by something that I thought would easily work.
I have a dataframe with year, city, and species columns.

```
           species      City  Year
80     Landpattedyr  Sisimiut 2007
83     Landpattedyr  Sisimiut 2008
87     Landpattedyr  Sisimiut 2009
721733  Havpattedyr Upernavik 2010
721734  Havpattedyr Upernavik 2011
721735  Havpattedyr Upernavik 2007
```

I have used the function unique as follows

```
years<-unique(df$year)
city<-unique(df$City)
species<-unique(df$species)
```

now I need to assign a value in each of those vectors to a dataframe row based on an index, for example

```
hunting[1,]$year<-year[i]
hunting[1,]$group<-species[j]
hunting[1,]$city<-city[k]
```

The problem is that only year is copied properly while city and species in the hunting df show up as numbers. I can't figure out why this is happening. Can anybody help please?

```
   year group city   lat   long total
1  2007     6   19 66.93 -53.66  4563
NA 2007     6   20 72.78 -56.15    91
3  2007     6    8 67.01 -50.72   388
4  2007     6   21 70.66 -52.12   280
5  2007     6   14 77.47 -69.23   469
6  2007     6    5 69.22 -51.10  1114
```

Comment: Probably because those two variables are factors. Convert them to character first.

Comment: To convert to char you can use this: `city <- unique(as.character(df$City))`, or simply this: `city <- levels(df$City)` (the last one works *only* with factors).

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft thank you guys, you are the bomb! If you type up the answer I can accept it. How do I know if a column in a df is a factor or char?

Comment: user4050: use `str(df)` for that; where df is the name of dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out if a column is factor or character you can use this `is.factor(df$City)` or `is.character(df$City)`.

In the case of a `factor` column, the (unique) levels are stored in the `levels` attribute, which can be accessed with

```
levels(df$City)
```

Note: this may include levels that are not present in the vector, for instance, if some rows have been removed or if some levels have been added.

To retrieve the unique elements of a `factor`or `character` vector, you can use this:

```
as.character(unique(df$City))
```

Which will *not* return levels that are not present in factor columns.

Note: the last command is slightly more efficient than `unique(as.character(df$City))`, since the conversion is evaluated on a possibly shorter vector.